# Can't log in with my login.jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC 4.1 and Spring Security 4.0. I want to use my own login page, but Spring Security always give me access denied page. If I use default login page everything is good. Here is my security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/"
                   access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login"
                   access="permitAll()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/signup"
                   access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout"
                   access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/errors/**"
                   access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/users"
                   access="hasRole('USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/forum"
                   access="hasRole('USER')"/>
    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler
            error-page="/errors/403"/>

    <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/login"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
    />


    <logout
            logout-success-url="/welcome"/>
    <!--logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"-->
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <!--<csrf/>-->
</http>


<b:import resource="classpath:ru/forque/service/applicationContext-service.xml"/>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

here is login.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
    <h1>Forque Sign In</h1>
    <c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl"/>
    <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                Failed to login.
                <c:if test="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null}">
                    Reason: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
                </c:if>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: so does spring not even allow you to see the /login page or is access denied after submitting completed login details on /login page?

Comment: spring redirects to access denied page after submitting

Comment: ok what do the logs/console output say when you submit the form? would be useful to see the log/console output. as an aside I don't see what page the user should be directed to upon successful login i.e. in my app the user is sent to /menu courtesy of the code: default-target-url="/menu" added to the form-login tags

Comment: PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/errors/403] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
      because I haven't already added error pages, but why spring security 
redirected to the 403 page?

Comment: I also don't see where your authentication check is being carried out, in my login.jsp I have (within the HTML form tags) the following: <form action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check'
    method='POST'>

Comment: Oh, I thought in Spring security 4 we could omit this parameter and just put /login

Comment: ah that may well be correct, apologies

Comment: it's ok. Thanks for helping me. But I haven't solved this problem yet. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by removing login-processing url

```
<form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-url="/Access_Denied"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. When I use custom login page, everything ok. Could you explain me what should I do to build my own login page?

Comment: Do you have your own request mapping for login?? instead of j_spring_secrity_check

Comment: Yes, it looks like: @RequestMapping(value = "/login",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showLoginForm() {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }

Comment: In Spring 4.0+ the processing URL needs to be defined explicitly. It is not `j_spring_security_check` anymore. it defaults to `/login`